# mongodb how to get all document with max value in one field from collections

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, find, aggregate

I have a collection with all my history biking
Each document contains type, start date start time, Avg speed, Avg power, Avg Heart rate.
I need to get the record with type = "road" including all fields with the highest Avg power
I found 2 ways

1. one aggregation – match (to select road) , sort and limit 1
2. first aggregation – match (to select road) , get the max power using group
   second aggregation to find the document with Avg power = max power

Both ways are working correctly but they are working too much
The first sort all documents to find the max one
The second create two aggregation

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  Given:

```
var r =
[
 {_id:0, road:"A", avgpower: 10, hr: 110},
 {_id:7, road:"A", avgpower: 14, hr: 109},
 {_id:1, road:"B", avgpower: 12, hr: 140},
 {_id:2, road:"B", avgpower: 14, hr: 130},
 {_id:3, road:"B", avgpower: 14, hr: 120},
 {_id:4, road:"B", avgpower: 10, hr: 117}
 ];
db.foo.insert(r);
```

then this pipeline:

```
c = db.foo.aggregate([
// Filter on road and get the highest avg power:                                 
{$match: {road: "B"}}
,{$sort: {avgpower: -1}}
,{$limit: 1}

// Now, do another query against the same collection, filtering                  
// by road AND the highest avg power:                                            
,{$lookup: {
        from: "foo",
        let: { mm: "$avgpower", rr: "$road" },
        pipeline: [
{$match: {$expr: {$and: [
{$eq: ["$avgpower", "$$mm"] }
,{$eq: ["$road", "$$rr" ]}
                     ]
        }}}
        ],
        as: "ZZ"}}

// The lookup will yield an array.  If this is not convenient,                   
// then turn the array into separate docs and make the "ZZ"                      
// object become the new root:                                                   
,{$unwind: "$ZZ"}
,{$replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$ZZ" }}
  ]);
```

yields this output:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "road" : "B", "avgpower" : 14, "hr" : 130 }
{ "_id" : 3, "road" : "B", "avgpower" : 14, "hr" : 120 }
```

Here's another approach:  use `$group` to create and array and then filter on it.  You can `$unwind` and `$replaceRoot` as before if desired:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$match: {road: "B"}}

,{$group: {_id: null, maxp: {$max: "$avgpower"}, items: {$push: "$$CURRENT"} }}

,{$project: {"X": {$filter: {
        input: "$items",
        as: "zz",
        cond: {$eq:[ "$$zz.avgpower", "$maxp" ]}
        }}
    }}
  ]);
```